# Function inside a Function not calling in React Native

Tags: function, react-native, react-native-ios

I am new to react-native and calling a function inside a fucntion.

I have done as below so far :

Step 1 : Created a function **_snapshotToArray** to convert the firebase snapshot to Arrray.

```
_snapshotToArray(snapshot) {
var returnArr = [];

snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var item = childSnapshot.val();
    item.key = childSnapshot.key;

    returnArr.push(item);
});
return returnArr;
 }
```

Step 2 : Created another function as below and calling **_snapshotToArray** inside it.

```
_readUserDataFromFirebaseConsole() {//once and on
firebase.database().ref('Users/').on('value', function (snapshot) {
    console.log(this._snapshotToArray(snapshot));
    Toast.show(this._snapshotToArray(snapshot),Toast.LONG);
});
}
```

Talking about this call :

```
console.log(this._snapshotToArray(snapshot));
```

When I press CTRL+CLick, it not letting me to navigate to body of the fuction **_snapshotToArray**.

In Device am getting below error :

**_snapshotToArray is not defined**

What might be the issue ?

Comment: Are you binding the function in the constructor?

Comment: no calling parent function in componentDidMount() as here : componentDidMount() {
    //this._callApiTogetFlowerData();
    this._readUserDataFromFirebaseConsole();
   
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at my PC right now, so I cannot test it, but from looking at your code, you need to use a different function notation to allow the varibale access of/from parent methods and parent class.

```
_snapshotToArray = snapshot => {
    var returnArr = [];

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var item = childSnapshot.val();
        item.key = childSnapshot.key;

        returnArr.push(item);
    });
    return returnArr;
}
```

and

```
_readUserDataFromFirebaseConsole = () => {
    firebase.database().ref('Users/').on('value', snapshot => {
        console.log(this._snapshotToArray(snapshot));
        Toast.show(this._snapshotToArray(snapshot),Toast.LONG);
    });
}
```